# How to avoid redundant second query to database with using MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, database, data-binding, mvvm

How to avoid redundant second query to database with using MVVM pattern on view model:

```
public class DataFormViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int companyId
    public int CompanyId
    {
        get { return companyId; }
        set 
        { 
            companyId = value; 
            RaisePropentyChanged("FindingStatuses");
            RaisePropentyChanged("StatusCount");
        }
    }

    public List<FindingStatus> FindingStatuses
    {
        get 
        {
            return FindingStatusService.GetAvalableStatuses(CompanyId);
        }
    }

    public int StatusCount
    {
        get { return FindingStatuses.Count; }
    }
}
```

i.e. when `CompanyId` was changed by DataBinder `FindingStatuses` will be executed and then `StatusCount` will be executed, that will execute `FindingStatuses` again.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'd bind the property directly to a database operation in the first place. Why not have a local `List<FindingStatus>` representing the "last fetched" statuses, and then explicitly refresh it?

Apart from anything else, property access is *usually* expected to be reasonably cheap - making a database call *every time* you access either of those properties sounds like a bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jon already mentioned, accessing properties are expected to be cheap, something you can do a thousand times without any sideeffect.

I would cache the result of your database access and return the cached object on any following request. Ie

```
private IList<FindingStatus> _findingStatuses;
public IList<FindingStatus> FindingStatuses
{
    get 
    {
        if (_findingStatuses == null) 
        {
             _findingStatuses = FindingStatusService.GetAvalableStatuses(CompanyId);
        }

        return _findingStatuses;
    }
}
```

And then you would of course have to clear your cache before raising the notification

```
public int CompanyId
{
    get { return companyId; }
    set 
    { 
        companyId = value;

        _findingStatuses = null;
        RaisePropentyChanged("FindingStatuses");

        RaisePropentyChanged("StatusCount");
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to return a `ReadOnlyCollection` instead of the internal mutable list.

Comment: Good point! Depending on you can actually add new statuses to this property or not though, i would maybe either rename the property or expose it as a method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid multiple (and useless) queries to the database, is implement a simple cache layer in the Data Access Layer.

1- Ask the cache if he already has an updated result
2- Else query the database

Here is a cache class you can try: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/andregenericcache.aspx